# What is the purpose to let *args, **kwargs in a parent class?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Trying to understand the wonderful:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-vii-error-handling i found this interesting line:

```
super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs).
```

I suppose that we just call the parent class `FlaskForm` and the signature of the `__init__` of this class is probably sommethnig like `__init__(*args,**kwargs)` and was wondering what was the purpose of including `*args,**kwargs` ...

Is this a way to let the users add any extra arguments later after inheriting ?

```
class EditProfileForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired()])
    about_me = TextAreaField('About me', validators=[Length(min=0, max=140)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def __init__(self, original_username, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.original_username = original_username
```

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/3001761

Comment: This allows the subclass to accept all the same arguments as the parent class, and pass them along transparently to the parent.